# Send Mail when SQL value is True

Tags: php, mysql, email

So, I'm kind of in a rut for over a day now because of this issue. I have a PHP wherein it gets called by Cron on a set amount. It gets called and executes just fine without much problems except for the styling. What it does is query the database on a set time for a value and if it's true then it proceeds to email that to the designated email that I put in the script. It's doing it's job but the problem is the format when the email gets delivered. The email looks like this when I open it:

[image: Email format image]

The issue, as you can see is that only the first line or row gets formatted on the table and the rest of the results doesn't follow it.

Here's the current script I'm using with some omitted/changed details.

```
#!/path/to/php
<?php
//DB
$dbconnect=new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$result=$dbconnect->query("SELECT `uid`,`pid`,`pdesc`,`umail`,`name` FROM `db_table` WHERE `pid`<='6'");
//if there are any records matching this query send an email listing each one using 'uid' as the identifier
if($result->num_rows>=1) {
$to = 'test@test.com';
$subject = "TEST FOR PRIZES NOTIFICATION";

$headers = 'From: sender@test.com' . "\r\n" .
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
$headers = "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: rep@test.com' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= 'THIS IS A TEST!';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= '<tr>
            <td>User ID</td>
            <td>Display Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Price</td>
    <td>Price Description</td></tr>';
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $message .= "<tr><td>".$row['uid']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['umail']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['pid']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['pdesc']."</td></tr>";
  $message .= "</table>";
  $message .= "</body></html>";
}
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  //mail successfully sent
} else {
  //mail unsuccessful
}
}
?>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Close the table outside the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the table inside of your loop, so it's closed after the first entry. Change your code from this:

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $message .= "<tr><td>".$row['uid']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['umail']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['pid']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['pdesc']."</td></tr>";
  $message .= "</table>";
  $message .= "</body></html>";
}
```

to this:

```
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $message .= "<tr><td>".$row['uid']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['umail']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['pid']."</td>";
  $message .= "<td>".$row['pdesc']."</td></tr>";
}
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
```

to close the table at the end.

Comment: I think I might've tried that one last time but it didn't went through though I might be wrong. I'll choose you as the answer if it works. So, thanks in advance!